# How to do back conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8, wstring

In order to convert `std::wstring` to UTF-8 I use the following code:

```
std::wstring my_wide_string = L"my_sqlite_db.db";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > myconv;
myconv.to_bytes( my_wide_string.c_str() );
```

Now, I need to do a back conversion, i.e. UTF-8  to `std::wstring`.

What is the proper way to switch the converter?

Comment: Absolutely no research effort in evidence here. What prevented you from consulting the documentation?

Comment: `std::wstring_convert::to_bytes()` accepts a `std::wstring` as input, so there is no need to call `c_str()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [`from_bytes()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/wstring_convert/from_bytes/) the reverse function:

```
std::wstring test = myconv.from_bytes(myutf8);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/VgTI55)